# Storing CLLocation2DCoordinates in C array - dynamically setting array size doesn't work

Tags: ios, nsarray, mkoverlay

I am trying to write an app that uses a map view to add overlays. The overlay data are loaded from a file into an NSArray which looks like this:
...

```
Revier355_2_Poly, //name of the polygon (string) 
6,                //no of coordinates of polygon (int) 
47.4038673907557, //latitude of first coordinate (double)  
8.5247885145479,  //longitude of first coordinate (double)
47.4035082236459,
8.52436382148047,
47.4031174379495,
8.52493568571008,
47.403348653295,
8.52586444637587,
47.4037666977377,
8.52550468311683,
47.4038673907557,
8.5247885145479
```

... next polygon with name, point count, coordinates.

Now I want to convert the above data into MKPolygons and place them in an NSDictionary. In order to do that I want to create C arrays containing the coordinates of each polygon in the file. This requires to set the number of items in the array dynamically at runtime.
Here is my problem: I don't manage to do this. Can you please help or point me in the right direction?

Here is the code I wrote

```
int i = 0;
    NSArray *data = [self loadDatafromFile];
    NSMutableDictionary *overlays = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for ( i=0; i<data.count;i++)
    {

        if ([[data objectAtIndex: i] isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
            //start of new Polygon called Revier
        {
            //Name of Revier
            NSString *polyName = (NSString*)[data objectAtIndex: i];               
            //PointCount is second entry after name
            int noOfPoints = [[data objectAtIndex: (i+1)] intValue];                    
            //Revier coordinates Error while setting Array size dynamically
            CLLocationCoordinate2D *coord = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * noOfPoints);                          
            for (int j=0; j<noOfPoints+1; j+=2)
                {

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D currCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[data objectAtIndex:j+i] doubleValue],[[data objectAtIndex:j+i+1] doubleValue]);
                     coord[j] = currCoord;

                }
            MKPolygon *p = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coord count:noOfPoints];
            [overlays setObject: p forKey:polyName];
            free(coord);
        }

    }
```

here is the code for loading the data...

```
- (NSArray *)loadDatafromFile
{
    NSArray* myArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self filePath]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self filePath]);
    return myArr;
}

- (NSString *) filePath
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"polygone" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSLog(@"%@",path);
    return path;

}
```

Comment: I also tried to set the array size for coord like this: CLLocation2DCoordinate coord[noOfPoints]; however, that didn't work either.

Comment: Please add the code for `-loadDatafromFile`

Comment: Is your txt file actually in the format as shown?  The initWithContentsOfFile method of NSArray requires the file to be in plist (xml) format.  If you want to read the txt file as-is, you'd have to use NSString's stringWithContentsOfFile method and then manually parse the string which is unreliable and unnecessary work.  If you put your data in plist format, it will be much easier to read it into an array of dictionaries which can then be easily used to construct MKPolygon objects.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But the data is already in a plist format. What I posted above was the content of the NSArray after I load the plist. However, could you please give a bit more information on how to use the dictionary to construct MKPolygons?

Comment: PS: Here is what the beginning of the plist I use to load the data looks like: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<string>Revier1_Poly</string>
<integer>204</integer>
<real>47.22012717</real><real>8.808388347</real>
<real>47.2394585400515</real><real>8.79568994231076</real>

Comment: I am not able to answer in detail right now but your issue is with the inner `for j` loop.  The indexes used to get the lat and long are wrong, the index used to set coord[] is wrong, the `j<noOfPoints+1` is wrong (should be `j < (noOfPoints*2)`).  But all this work would be eliminated if the plist itself contained the array of dictionaries that you are manually constructing.

Comment: Haha. So many mistakes. Thanks for pointing them out. I guess I will try the suggested approach with an array of dictionaries saved in the plist. However, I still don't know how I can construct an MKPolygon from a dictionary. My initial approach will be to put one into a dictionary, put the dictionary into an array and save the array to a file. From there on I'll work my way backwards so that I know how to structure the input plist for the apps.

Comment: With a better plist layout, a lot of this work will be avoided.  You would still need to create the C array at run-time out of the NSArray you'd get from the plist.  However, if you are planning to later save the MKPolygon object itself, I would not recommend that.  I believe you'd have to switch to saving as NSData.  Instead, only use the MKPolygon objects at run-time to add them to the map.  Otherwise, just work with plist-compatible objects such as arrays, dictionaries, NSNumbers, etc.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to save any MKPolygons at run time. However, I am looking for a way to load the Polygons that I want to display with the app from a file. I am not going to manipulate any polygons in the app - they are only going to be displayed. Is there a better mechanism to do that than a plist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here are the problems with your existing code which is manually parsing the individual elements as one large flat array...

The `for j` loop has the following issues:

- `j<noOfPoints+1` should be `j < (noOfPoints*2)` since there are two array elements to process for each point
- The indexes to get the latitude and longitude from the `data` array are wrong (in the line that sets `currCoord`).  By the way, that line would be ***much*** easier to read, understand, and (especially important) to debug if it was split up into multiple statements.  The corrected code might look like this:

  ```
  int latitudeIndex = j+i +2;     //need to add additional offset of +2
  int longitudeIndex = j+i+1 +2;  //need to add additional offset of +2

  CLLocationDegrees lat = [[data objectAtIndex:latitudeIndex] doubleValue];
  CLLocationDegrees lon = [[data objectAtIndex:longitudeIndex] doubleValue];

  CLLocationCoordinate2D currCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lon);
  ```
- The index used to set the element in the C array is wrong.  In the line `coord[j] = currCoord;`, `j` will be `0` initially but then increments by `2`.  So you end up setting `coord[0]`, `coord[2]`, etc. and leaving the odd indexes uninitialized.  Instead, add a separate counter as the index to set the C array (though it could be calculated from `j`, a separate counter is cleaner and easier to understand or change):

  ```
  int coordIndex = 0;  //declare and initialize before the for-j loop
  for (int j=0;...
  {
      ...  //code to set currCoord

      coord[coordIndex] = currCoord;
      coordIndex++;
  }
  ```

Those changes should fix the parsing and creation of the polygon objects but there are two other general issues:

- The code manually parses each individual element in the array making it difficult to write, understand, and change.
- The code basically reads the plist twice because the outer loop has to read through elements that the inner loop has already processed.  The outer loop skips these by checking if the element type is a string or not.

Both of these can be resolved by using a better plist format and letting the built-in plist reading methods do the hard work for you.  All you'll have to do is create the C array.

Here is a possible alternative plist format for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PolygonName</key>
        <string>Revier355_2_Poly</string>
        <key>Coordinates</key>
        <array>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.4038673907557</real><key>Longitude</key><real>8.5247885145479</real></dict>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.4035082236459</real><key>Longitude</key><real>8.52436382148047</real></dict>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.4031174379495</real><key>Longitude</key><real>8.52493568571008</real></dict>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.403348653295</real><key>Longitude</key><real>8.52586444637587</real></dict>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.4037666977377</real><key>Longitude</key><real>8.52550468311683</real></dict>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.4038673907557</real><key>Longitude</key><real>8.5247885145479</real></dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>PolygonName</key>
        <string>Revier1_Poly</string>
        <key>Coordinates</key>
        <array>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.22012717</real><key>Longitude</key><real>8.808388346999999</real></dict>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.2394585400515</real><key>Longitude</key><real>8.79568994231076</real></dict>
            <dict><key>Latitude</key><real>47.1394585400515</real><key>Longitude</key><real>4.89568994231076</real></dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

The code to read this plist would be something like this:

```
NSArray *polygonsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableDictionary *overlays = [NSMutableDictionary new];

//loop through the polygon dictionaries...
for (NSDictionary *polygonDict in polygonsArray) 
{
    NSString *polyName = [polygonDict objectForKey:@"PolygonName"];
    NSArray *coordDictionaries = [polygonDict objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

    //loop through the array of coordinate dictionaries for the 
    //current polygon to create C array of coordinates...
    int noOfPoints = coordDictionaries.count;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *coord = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * noOfPoints);

    int coordIndex = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *coordDict in coordDictionaries) 
    {
        CLLocationDegrees lat = [[coordDict objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees lon = [[coordDict objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D currCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lon);
        coord[coordIndex] = currCoord;
        coordIndex++;
    }

    MKPolygon *p = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coord count:noOfPoints];
    [overlays setObject:p forKey:polyName];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:p];
    free(coord);
}
```

Note the only index calculation you have to deal with is for the C array.

If you need a more advanced or standardized format, you could also look at [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#polygons).  There is also the [KMLViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app from Apple though I think the sample code only parses polylines.

Regarding your question in the comments:

> Is there a better mechanism to do that than a plist?

This depends on how much data you are expecting to store.  If the plist is not fast enough for your app, you'll have to switch to a method that allows random access of data (eg. a SQL database or multiple plists).  That is probably worth a separate question if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this great, detailed answer. I'll get right to it. Regarding the amount of data/polygons I am going to process: It will be about 500 polygons I estimate. So I hope that the plist approach should be feasible.